# Ionic View not recognized in chrome://inspect

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools, ionic-view

I want to debug my hybride application via the Ionic View App, using the chrome://inspect tab of my desktop chrome browser. I connected my device (Nexus 4) and can open the console for all other opened webpages in Android's chrome-browser. As described in the ionic.io documentation (http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/chrome-inspector), I should also see the Ionic View App appear in the inspect menu but that isn't the case... Am I doing something wrong? I installed the right driver for my device and can see and inspect other mobile webpages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've built the app **without** *--release* flag, and also that cordova console is installed.
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
ionic build android`

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured your device?

## Steps

- On your device: enable USB Debugging.
- Connect your device via USB.
- In Chrome in the 'inspect' tab (`chrome://inspect`) check the option `Discover USB Devices`.

Check the [Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) for more information, maybe you are missing something.

Comment: You're right, but if my configuration was wrong, I think I couldn't inspect anything. Now I can inspect every chrome tab on my browser, but on ionic view...

Comment: What about versions of chrome in desktop and android? [Requirements](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#requirements). What's your device's OS version?